# adding custom field to woo product page (only for certain product id)

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to add custom tab on product page, but i want it show it only for some product ids.

Here my code for adding the custom tab on front end.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;
}
```

and then i should add below function too for displaying the content.

```
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    echo '<p>some text</p>';
}
```

but now these function work for all product ids. I want to load this two function only for some product id, could someone help me?

I tired to add `if(is_product() && get_the_id() == 8)` on both functions but `$tabs` not appear on others product ids page , ( on product id "8" `$tabs` worked well )

Comment: fixed. i just need to return $tabs after closing the if

Comment: If you have self-solved, you may answer your own question.  When posting, please be as clear and educational as possible.  Eventually, you will be able to accept your own answer so that your issue is deemed resolved in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem of that code wast about to forget return `$tabs`

```
if(is_product()) {
//if(is_product())) {
return $tabs;
}
return $tabs;
}
```

so the final code could be like this.

```
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
if(condition) {
$tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 50,
    'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
);
return $tabs;
}
return $tabs;
}
```